# Python, problem with tkinter entry function

Tags: python, tkinter

When i write this in my python code, it display the next error. What can i do to repair it?

```
filename = tkinter.StringVar()
entry_function = tkinter.Entry(parent, textvariable=filename, bg="black", font=("Hacker", 15, "normal"),fg= "white", width = 18)
tkinter.Entry.insert(0,'keylogger')
tkinter.Entry.pack(default)
```

Error

```
  Messaggio=insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
  Origine=D:\finale\Homework.py
  Analisi dello stack:
  File "D:\finale\Homework.py", line 138, in <module>
    tkinter.Entry.insert(0,'keylogger')
```

Comment: You should instantiate `tkinter.Entry` first: `the_entry = tkinter.Entry(<whatever_arguments_here>); the_entry.insert(0, 'keylogger')` etc

Comment: I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define a `Entry` widget, and then insert a value.

Here is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

ent = tk.Entry(window, width=20)
ent.grid(row=0, column=0)

# insert value
ent.insert(0,'keylogger')

window.mainloop()
```